# indesign GREP for serial commas

Tags: regex, grep, automation, adobe-indesign

*For the broader scope of my challenge-at-hand, I have been looking for a usable InDesign GREP statement to help automate the conversion of serial commas from the non-Oxford style to the Oxford comma (and vice versa).*

For the purposes of simplifying this question for the SE community I will limit the challenge to using GREP to FIND non-Oxford style commas.

I have used two expressions, both of which draw in too much content:

1. from my own development:

   ```
   ,(.*?),(.*?) and (.*?)
   ```

Result:

> , and the possibility of detecting signs of life, biomarkers, occupies
>   the thoughts of many researchers. Such measurements may be possible
>   with the next generation of large aperture optical telescopes. Looking
>   back to the Big Bang, we are now on the verge of measuring the impact
>   of gravitational waves generated by quantum effects during the
>   Inflationary epoch, an era when the Universe expanded at unprecedented
>   rates. Aside from generating important new knowledge, modern astronomy
>   both utilizes and

2. from an InDesign user forum:

   `(?<=\w,)(.+)(.*?)(?= and)`

Result:

> and the possibility of detecting signs of life, biomarkers, occupies
>   the thoughts of many researchers. Such measurements may be possible
>   with the next generation of large aperture optical telescopes. Looking
>   back to the Big Bang, we are now on the verge of measuring the impact
>   of gravitational waves generated by quantum effects during the
>   Inflationary epoch, an era when the Universe expanded at unprecedented
>   rates. Aside from generating important new knowledge, modern astronomy
>   both utilizes

As you can see neither result picks up a serial comma and both are too broad to be effective.

I've struggled with this, but can not find a reasonable solution on the Web. I thought I would ply the great minds of the SE community, including coders of regex and users of other GREP tools.

I thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: What about `,\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)*,\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)* and\b`? Have you got any specifications? Test cases?

Comment: I don't spot the Oxford comma(s) in your sample phrases. Can you point them out?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wiktor, I think your code narrows the scope down the best, so far; but it's still picking up phrases and other such. I suspect that English is just too complex to allow automation to fix everything. Still, your having narrowed the text down will help with my problem. Thanking you.

Comment: @RadLexus Rad, the sample is a serial list with no Oxford comma, to which the comma _would_ be added before the final "and".

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is too wide, and to find a 100% working solution is next to impossible. To get rid of the most evident false positives, you may use the following pattern:

```
,\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)*,\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)* and\b
```

Or, replace `\w` with `\p{L}` to only match letters:

```
,\s*\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*,\s*\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)* and\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AoqzCZ/1).

**Details**:

- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\p{L}+` - 1+ letters
- `(?:\s+\p{L}+)*`  - zero or more sequences of 1+ whitespaces and 1+ letters
- `,\s*\p{L}+` - the same as above
- `(?:\s+\p{L}+)*`  - the same as above
- `+and\b` - 1+ spaces followed with `and` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary).

This can be further enhanced to fit more specific contexts.